# reproducible results by set.seed

Tags: machine-learning, r

Is it possible for results to fluctuate a little bit even if I set set.seed? Kindly comment on the degree of freedom allowed or the possible standard deviation from the result set if seeds are fixed?

I set seeds in R and I get slightly varied results ranging from 0.1 to 0.5 S.D from previous runs. I want to know if it is normal

Comment: Can you show your “reproducible” code?

Comment: If nothing else changes, then your results should be the same if you set a seed, unless some part of your analysis, after the seed is set, involves random sampling.